# PDF table of contents, and some character accents

Tags: hyperref, pdf, accents, bookmarks

When I create a document with pdftex, I use chapter and section titles, and -through using babel- also accented characters. In the document itself these characters appear OK. Most of them appears correctly in the navigation pane of the left side of the main window. However, the so called Hungarian accents are only correct in the main window, but in the navigation pane only the unaccented character appears. For example, when typing `\"o`, `\H{}o` in the text file, in the document ö and ő appears, but in the navigation pane only ö and o. What is the difference between these two kinds of accents, and how to fix it? Is it LaTex, pdftex, PDF?

Comment: not answering the question, but `\H{}o` isn't going to position the accent accurately.  this should be either `\H o` (this will preserve kerning with adjacent letters) or `\H{o}` (which will suppress kerning).  can't give an authoritative answer regarding the navigation panel, but suspect that only if a single pre-accented letter is in the input will it appear correctly in the navigation panel.